# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "zueco", "haloza" y "colodro"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ropa

[Zueco](https://dle.rae.es/zueco?):

> 1. m. Zapato de madera de una pieza.

[Haloza](https://dle.rae.es/haloza?):

> 1. f. Calzado de madera.

[Colodro](https://dle.rae.es/colodro)

> 1. m. desus. Especie de calzado de madera.

A la vista de las definiciones, parece que las 3 palabras corresponden a calzado de madera y que la única diferencia entre ellas es que el zueco es *de una pieza* y colodro es *desusado*.

¿Son esas las únicas diferencias, o hay otras como la forma, uso en distintas zonas geográficas, etc.?

Comment: Segun Google N-grams ni haloza ni colodro se usan mucho.

Answer (score 1):

El `colodro` tiene calcañar, para fijar mejor el pie. La `haloza` tienen piezas en la suela para alzarla más del suelo y evitar que el pie se manche de fango. Los `zuecos` tradicionales no  tienen talonera nunca.

Zueco [image: Zueco]

Haloza
[image: Haloza]

Colodro
[image: colodro]

Answer (score 0):

La etimología de `haloza` es que desciende del francés o del occitano y significan sandalia. Los `zuecos` cubren todo el pie en madera; una sandalia puede usar madera solo en la suela. `Haloza` y `colodro` no los escuché en la vida diaria; `zueco`, aunque poco, si.